# Python Get All Images of an Instagram Post

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, screen-scraping

I am writing code in Python to extract all posts of a user on Instagram. I have written the code to extract the 12 most recent posts of an Insta user:

```
import urllib.request as reqq
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = input("Enter the link:")

start_time = time.time()

browser = webdriver.Chrome("D:\\Python_Files\\Programs\\chromedriver.exe")

browser.get(url)

urls = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('article > div a')
url_list = []

for element in urls:
    url_list.append(element.get_attribute('href'))
 
count = 1

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

start_time = time.time()

for x in url_list:
    img_url = ""
    vid_url = ""
    
    browser.maximize_window()
    browser.get(x)
    
    try:        
        vid_url = browser.find_element_by_class_name('_5wCQW').find_element_by_tag_name('video').get_attribute('src')
        reqq.urlretrieve(vid_url,"D:\\instavid"+str(count)+".mp4")        
    except:         
        img_url = browser.find_element_by_class_name('KL4Bh').find_element_by_tag_name('img').get_attribute('src')
        reqq.urlretrieve(img_url,f"D:\\instaimg"+str(count)+".jpg")
    count+=1
    
browser.close()

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

The problem is that there are a few posts that have multiple images. The current code only extracts the first image of multi-image posts. Is there any way to extract all images from a multi-image post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if the right chevron element exists or not whenever you open post
a class '.    coreSpriteRightChevron' exists so you need to check if that element exits or not if it exists then its multiple image post.

here is the selector path I found from browser.

```
body > div._2dDPU.CkGkG > div.zZYga > div > article > div._97aPb > div > div.pR7Pc > div.Igw0E.IwRSH.eGOV_._4EzTm.O1flK.D8xaz.fm1AK.TxciK.yiMZG > div > button > div
```

if the selector returns null/None then its single image post else its multi Image.

Also avoid using selenium and use instagram's reverse engineered api. Checkout [this](https://github.com/ping/instagram_private_api) repo for more details.